# How do I populate text boxes properly from a XML file on a selected ComboBox item?

Tags: xml, vb.net, combobox, xml-parsing

I have tried so many different ways to get this to work and it just keeps loading the first item. I need to be able to populate various text boxes with all the items from the XML file once the text is matched from the combobox.

Basically, I load my app, I FIRST read the XML file to load the ComboBox, then when I select an item from the ComboBox, I load other text boxes with the details of an error.

**My XML file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="us-ascii"?>
<!--SIP Data created by TECH on 1/24/2014 10:07:04 AM-->
<ERROR_ITEMS>
    <ERROR_DATA Posted="6/11/2018 12:00:00 PM">
        <Response>ERROR001</Response>
            <Method>ErrorCode001</Method>
                <Request>Acknowledged</Request>
                    <Code>001</Code>
                        <Information>Information for code 001 goes here</Information>
                            <Troubleshooting>Error 001 designates connections failed. Check all connections.</Troubleshooting>
                                <Additional_Notes>Tech notes: Ensure proper gauge of wiring.</Additional_Notes>
                                    <DateTimeSaved>11/10/2014 1:45:25 PM</DateTimeSaved>
        <Response>ERROR002</Response>
            <Method>ErrorCode002</Method>
                <Request>Acknowledged</Request>
                    <Code>002</Code>
                        <Information>Information for code 002 goes here</Information>
                            <Troubleshooting>Error 002 designates input power failed. Check power to aux inputs.</Troubleshooting>
                                <Additional_Notes>Tech notes: Check all power connections</Additional_Notes>
                                    <DateTimeSaved>11/10/2014 1:50:25 PM</DateTimeSaved>
  </ERROR_DATA>
</ERROR_ITEMS>
```

**And my VB.net code:**

```
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Text
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Environment
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub ExitAppBTN_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ExitAppBTN.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Try
            ' LOAD THE ERRORS INTO THE COMBO BOX
            Dim document As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument
            document.Load(Application.StartupPath & "/items.xml")

            For Each node In document.SelectNodes("ERROR_ITEMS/ERROR_DATA/Response")
                CmboERRORList.Items.Add(node.InnerText())
            Next

            'Load First Item
            CmboERRORList.SelectedIndex = 0
            CmboERRORList.Focus()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Error processing file. The error was: " & vbCrLf & Err.Description, MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Error loading file contents to drop down list.")
        End Try
    End Sub

        Private Sub CmboERRORList_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CmboERRORList.SelectedIndexChanged
                Try
                    'Load info from the XML file

                    Dim document As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument
                    document.Load(Application.StartupPath & "/items.xml")
                    Dim node = document.SelectSingleNode("ERROR_ITEMS/ERROR_DATA[Response = '" & CmboERRORList.Text & "']")
                    MsgBox(node.SelectSingleNode("Method").InnerText)

                    For Each node In document.SelectNodes("ERROR_ITEMS/ERROR_DATA[Response = '" & CmboERRORList.Text & "']")
                        Dim ErrResponseCode = node.SelectSingleNode("Method").InnerText
                        Dim ErrDetails = node.SelectSingleNode("Information").InnerText
                        txtDetails.Text = ErrDetails
                    Next

                Catch ex As Exception
                    MsgBox("Error Reading Error Data File, please contact technical support. Error is: " & Err.Description & vbCrLf & "Error Number is :" & Err.Number, MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Error")
                End Try
            End Sub
```

Comment: Does your Xml really look like the sample you have provided? It does not look hierarchical, but a very flat structure. This structure won't be read effectively using the XmlDocument class, for this you need to use an XmlReader

Comment: Yep. Been using that for years just never searched through it. I usually had a single XML file for each item but now want to use just one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this instead of your current ComboBox SelectedIndexChanged event handler.

```
Private Sub CmboERRORList_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CmboERRORList.SelectedIndexChanged
    Try
        'Load info from the XML file

        Dim settings As New XmlReaderSettings()
        settings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Parse
        Dim reader As XmlReader = XmlReader.Create("XmlFile1.xml", settings)
        Dim found As Boolean = False
        Dim nodeName As String = String.Empty
        Dim nodeText As String = String.Empty
        While reader.Read
            Select Case reader.NodeType
                Case XmlNodeType.Element
                    nodeName = reader.Name
                Case XmlNodeType.Text
                    nodeText = reader.Value
            End Select

            If (nodeName = "Response" AndAlso nodeText = CmboERRORList.Text) Then
                found = True
            End If

            If (found AndAlso nodeName = "Method" AndAlso reader.NodeType = XmlNodeType.Text) Then
                Debug.WriteLine("Method = " & reader.Value)
            ElseIf (found AndAlso nodeName = "Request" AndAlso reader.NodeType = XmlNodeType.Text) Then
                Debug.WriteLine("Request = " & reader.Value)
            ElseIf (found AndAlso nodeName = "Code" AndAlso reader.NodeType = XmlNodeType.Text) Then
                Debug.WriteLine("Code = " & reader.Value)
            ElseIf (found AndAlso nodeName = "Information" AndAlso reader.NodeType = XmlNodeType.Text) Then
                Debug.WriteLine("Information = " & reader.Value)
                txtDetails.Text = reader.Value
            ElseIf (found AndAlso nodeName = "Troubleshooting" AndAlso reader.NodeType = XmlNodeType.Text) Then
                Debug.WriteLine("Troubleshooting = " & reader.Value)
            ElseIf (found AndAlso nodeName = "Additional_Notes" AndAlso reader.NodeType = XmlNodeType.Text) Then
                Debug.WriteLine("Additional_Notes = " & reader.Value)
            ElseIf (found AndAlso nodeName = "DateTimeSaved" AndAlso reader.NodeType = XmlNodeType.Text) Then
                Debug.WriteLine("DateTimeSaved = " & reader.Value)

                Exit While
            End If
        End While
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Error Reading Error Data File, please contact technical support. Error is: " & Err.Description & vbCrLf & "Error Number is :" & Err.Number, MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Error")
    End Try
End Sub
```

Here I am using the `XmlReader` class to read the Xml line by line. If your Xml Document isn't hierarchical then the XmlReader is really the best option to go through it.

The XmlReader [(Link to MSDN)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader(v=vs.110).aspx) is very low-level, meaning that you need to check what you are reading at each stage and act accordingly. [More information on the Read method and how to handle the NodeTypes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.read(v=vs.110).aspx)

**Please note I put an Exit While in the last Else..If statement to terminate the While Loop as the DateTimeSaved node is the last one you are interested in**

Comment: BAM! Perfect. Thank you!